# Page messes up on hover of menu in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am having some issues with a website I'm working on. For some reason, only in IE7, the page completely messes up when you hover over the main menu at the top. On initial load of the page you can already see that the menu itself is positioned wrong, 15px to the left. When you the hover over the menu, the menu itself goes back into the right place and the rest of the page completely messes up.

page: http://www.ptwee.nl/referenties/

The site is built using the Skeleton Wordpress theme which uses superfish for the main navigation.

I also use https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ for rendering the responsive CSS in older IE browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a position relative on your .referenties it should fix your problem.